# label not showing up when properties changed to visable

Tags: vb.net

in my program I have a section that is outlined as listed below - in the page load, the label's visibility is set to false.

```
lblLoading.visable = true
lblloading.text = "loading please wait"
UpdateData()
lblloading.text = "Loading Complete"
```

It takes about a minute or 2 to run updatedata as it is doing multiple things to a database - when I execute this code, it stalls and loads the data, then when done I do get my label that says loading complete, but I never see the label before it is done loading to tell the user that it is processing. Is there any way to force it to show before UpdateData() is called so that it shows during the load time? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cant update a form while in a loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567296/cant-update-a-form-while-in-a-loop)

Comment: This is a common problem. The GUI doesn't get updated when you block the GUI thread with some computationally intensive task. The best solution is to use a `BackgroundWorker` component to spin off the work done by your `UpdateData()` function, freeing up the GUI thread to update the GUI.

Comment: @CodyGray - thank you, never used a backgroundworker before, will look into and report back

Comment: for anyone else with this issue, I am using this tutorial to get through my problem - http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/88605-the-background-worker/

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
Me.Refresh
```

before you call UpdateData

Comment: this does not seem to work or update the data - visual studio is not recognizing me.refresh and throwing an error

Comment: VS is giving you an error on Me.Refresh?  You are using VB.NET, correct.